# Checking what vertices are in the camera frustrum and making them another color (Shader)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

So I have just started working on shaders and I had this idea that I want to check what vertices is in the frustrum of the camera and make them a different color. My knowledge of shaders, matrixes etc comes from watching videos and reading posts so bear with me please haha

Outside of my shader I set the matrix of the camera. In the shader I then set the verex to the clip position, then I use a function to see if the vertice is in the frustrum and if it is I assign it to 1 or 0 that I later use to show the color;

The results i get is this:

[Few vertices only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPuup.png)

Only covering the multiple vertices that are directly in the centre of the camera.

This is the most essential code for it:

Code for outside the shader for updating the camera:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    Matrix4x4 M = transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().localToWorldMatrix;
    Matrix4x4 V = theCamera.worldToCameraMatrix;
    Matrix4x4 P = theCamera.projectionMatrix;
    Matrix4x4 MVP = P * V * M;
    Shader.SetGlobalMatrix("MvpCamera", MVP);
}
```

Function in Shader that checks if the vertice is in the cameras view:

```
bool CheckIfFrustrum(float4x4 matr, float4 point)
{
float4 VertexCheck = mul(matr, float4(point.x, point.y, point.z, 1));
    return VertexCheck.x > -1 && VertexCheck.x < 1 && VertexCheck.y > -1 && VertexCheck.y < 1;
}
```

The vert shader:

```
Interpolators vert (MeshData v)
{
    Interpolators o;

    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    o.color = CheckIfFrustrum(MvpCamera, o.vertex) ? 1 : 0;

    return o;
}
```

Tried working around with the CheckIfFrustrum function and change the return to:

```
return vertexCheck.y < 1  && vertexCheck.x < 1  && vertexCheck.z > 0;
```

Which makes it take up a quarter of the frustrum instead.
[Quater of frustrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZky.png)

If I only check the x or the y it covers half of the camera vertically or horizontally.

```
return vertexCheck.x > 1  && vertexCheck.z > 0;
```

Now if I only use the x values for the check I get a weird effect of a line with some of the white color inbetween:

```
return vertexCheck.x < 1 && vertexCheck.x > -1  && vertexCheck.z > 0;
```

[Weird line effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReiV5.png)

Any tips on what I can do to make it so that all the vertices in the camera frustrum creates one color?